# Printing a unique triangle of characters in java

Tags: java, for-loop, printing

I need to print a triangle of characters:

0

1 0

1 0 1

0 1 0 1

The code I have prints it as this:

0

1 0

0 1 0

1 0 1 0

I can print it alternating, but when I try to change from alternating to unique characters I run into issues.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //mod even = 0, mod 1 = odd
    int height;
    int zero = 0;
    int one = 1;
    height = 4;

    for(int i=1; i<=height; i++) {
        for(int j=1; j<=i; j++) {
            if ((j % 2) == 1) {
                System.out.print((i % 2 == 1) ? zero : one);
            } else {
                System.out.print((i % 2 == 1) ? one : zero);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


}
```

I've tried adding in the if statement a scenario such as

```
 if ((j % 2) == 1 && i == height){
      System.out.print((i % 2 == 1) ? one : zero);
 }
```

to get the last line to print starting with one, but it gets buggy and affects all lines. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the pattern here? Will there be a 5th line? If yes, should it start with 0 or 1

Comment: The pattern: if there were no `\n`, it's just be 0 1 0 1 0....  The first `\n` is after one character, the next after two, and so on.  You could probably write this as replacing spaces with newlines then adding a `\0` to end your output string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static void triangle(int height) {
        int valueToPrintNext = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
        {
            for(int j = -1; j < i; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(valueToPrintNext + " ");
                valueToPrintNext = valueToPrintNext==0 ? 1 : 0;
            }

            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Main:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        triangle(6);
    }
```

Output:

```
0 
1 0 
1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 
0 1 0 1 0 
1 0 1 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you're a programmer now.  Programmers start counting from 0, not 1.  PARTICULARLY in our for(){} loops.  You're almost certainly a student, so just keep working at it.

What you're printing is basically "1 0 1 0" with newLines sprinkled in... so that's exactly how I'm going to do it.

This shows you that there are at least two different approaches to solving this problem.  Bonus credit for anyone who comes up with a 3rd one (no not really).

Lets do a little numeric analysis to figure out the math on the total character count given a particular number of lines...

```
1 = 2 "1\n"
2 = 6 "1\n0 1\n"
3 = 12 "1\n0 1\n0 1 0\n"
4 = 20
5 = 30
6 = 42
n = n^2 + n
```

Okay, so now we write that up as a fairly trivial function.  Lots of little functions is always easier to write AND TEST than a few big ones.  Small functions good.  Big functions bad.

```
private int getEndOfLinePosition(int lines) {
    return lines * lines + lines;
}
```

And here we have the code which handles the aforementioned testing.  Unit tests are awesome.  Many people encourage you to write your unit tests BEFORE the code your testing.  A good idea, but one I have to work at to follow.  I like JUnit 5.

```
// imports go before your class at the top of the file
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

@Test
public void eolTest() {
    int correctLengths[] = {2, 6, 12, 20, 30, 42};
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        Assertions.assertEquals(correctLengths[i], getEndOfLinePosition(i + 1));
    }
}
```

We'll build two functions, one to build the ones and zeros, and the other two sprinkle in the new lines.  And we'll need a 'main' to glue 'em together.

```
void main() {
    int height = 4;
    StringBuffer onesAndZeros = buildOnesAndZeros(height);
    addNewlines(onesAndZeros, height);
    System.out.print(onesAndZeros);
}
```

There shouldn't be any surprises there... except perhaps that I'm using a StringBuffer rather than a String.  String is immutable in Java, StringBuffer is expressly intended to be messed with, and mess with it we shall.  Also, using print instead of println: our return will be built into the string.

```
private StringBuffer buildOnesAndZeroes(int height) {
    int stringLength = getEndOfLinePosition(height);
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(stringLength);
    char nextChar = '0';
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i += 2) {
        buffer.append(nextChar);
        buffer.append(' ');
        nextChar = i % 2 == 1 ? "1" : "0";
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

The expression to determine nextChar might be backwards, but that should be easy to detect and fix.  I may have even gotten it backwards on purpose just to leave you a bug to squish.

```
String addNewLines(StringBuffer onesAndZeros, int height) {
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i) {
        int currentEnd = getEndOfLinePosition(i);
        onesAndZeros.setCharAt(curentEnd - 1, '\n');
    }
}
```

Wrap all that in a class, and Bob's your uncle.  Where the hell does that expression come from anyway?  I mean... England, yeah, but why?!